# Object' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no accessible extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: c#, dataset

When trying to add a row i am getting the following error : Object' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no accessible extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
void RebuildTableView(DataSet ds)
     {
        string previousUser = "";  // track previous


        // loop through each row in the data set and create
        // the row on the web page in a web table

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            // add title (use a single column)
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());

            // change title color slightly
            tr.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Navy;
            tr.Cells[0].Width = 400;

            //  make the text title big and purple
            tr.Cells[0].Text = "<FONT SIZE=5 COLOR=purple FACE=Rockwell><B>" + dr[2].ToString() + "</B></FONT>";
            this.BlogTable.Rows.Add(tr);
```

Comment: Use As Enumerable : ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()

Comment: @jdweng Why would that change anything? A `DataRowCollection` already has a `GetEnumerator()` method, so you can use it in a foreach.

Comment: What is the type of `this.BlogTable`? I suspect it doesn't have a `Rows` property.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel : My code works.   Ops code gives errors.

Comment: How do you know if it works? I can't run that code, and neither can you, it's an incomplete snippet. And anyway, the error message mentioned isn't even about `ds.Tables[0].Rows`, it's about `this.BlogTable.Rows.Add(tr)`. You can't just throw unnecessary changes on top and hope it fixes unrelated errors.